# Check if string appears within node value in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<nodes>
  <node>
    <articles>125,1,9027</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>999,48,123</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>123,1234,4345,567</articles>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

I need to write some XSLT which will return only nodes which have a paricular article id, so in the example above, only those nodes which contain article 123.

My XSLT isn't great, so I'm struggling with this.  I'd like to do something like this, but I know of course there isn't an 'instring' extension method in XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentNodeId" select="1234"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$allNodes [instring(articles,$currentNodeId)]">
  <!-- Output stuff -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

I know this is hacky but not sure of the best approach to tackle this.  The node-set is likely to be huge, and the number of article ids inside the  nodes is likely to be huge too, so I'm pretty sure turning that splitting the value of the  node and turning it into a node-set isn't going to be very efficient, but I could be wrong!

Any help as to the best way to do this would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What XSLT version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 : This will match articles which have **exactly** 123 somewhere as text.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="id" select="123"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//node[matches(articles, concat('(^|\D)', $id, '($|\D)'))]">
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nodes>
  <node>
    <articles>1234,1000,9027</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>999,48,01234</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>123,1234,4345,567</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles> 123 , 456 </articles>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

Output :

```
123,1234,4345,567

 123 , 456
```

I don't know how to do this efficiently with XSLT 1.0 but as the OP said he is using XSLT 2.0 so this should be a sufficient answer.

Comment: Not a workable answer, this will also match *1234*, *2123* etc. Although it does serve as a response to the question of a search for an "instring" function.

Comment: I just simplified the previous answer which also has the same disadvantages. I will post one stricter solution soon.

Comment: @FailedDev, About what disadvantages of previous answer are you talking?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Your solution also matches this : <articles>1234,1000,9027</articles> Which is not what the OP wanted I assume.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk I deleted my XSLT 1.0 bad solution since you nailed it :)

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 you can use this simple solution, it uses `normalize-space`, `translate`, `contains`, `substring`, `string-length` functions.

Sample input XML:

```
<nodes>
  <node>
    <articles>125,1,9027</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>999,48,123</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>123,1234,4345,567</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles> 123 , 456 </articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>789, 456</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles> 123 </articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>456, 123 ,789</articles>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="id" select="123"/>

  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="translate(normalize-space(articles/.), ' ', '')"/>

    <xsl:if test="$s = $id 
            or contains($s, concat($id, ','))
            or substring($s, string-length($s) - string-length($id) + 1, string-length($id)) = $id">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>


  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/nodes">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<nodes>
  <node>
    <articles>999,48,123</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>123,1234,4345,567</articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles> 123 , 456 </articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles> 123 </articles>
  </node>
  <node>
    <articles>456, 123 ,789</articles>
  </node>
</nodes>
```